# Air: How to put a NativeWindow over OSX menu bar?

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, air, fullscreen, multiple-monitors

I'm developing a multi monitor fullscreen application with Adobe Air 2.6.

I can create a window for every monitor, and put those windows to fullscreen.

```
theWindow.stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
```

The problem comes when interacting with those windows. If I click the window on the main monitor (the one with the dock and menu bar) no problem, but when I click any other window the system menu bar becomes visible.

I've tried resizing the main window to match the monitor size and moving it to a negative coordinate but it always stays behind the bar.

Is it possible to do this in Air?
Should I look for another solution?

Comment: I don't believe you have a way to control this on Mac OS X. If that's for some "kiosk"/installation — switch to Windows.

Comment: In Windows it doesn't show dock or something once you focus on another fullscreen AIR window. Everything stays fullscreen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to go full FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE using AIR 3.1 (Flex 4.6 SDK) on OSX using a terrible timer hack:

```
public function initializeView():void
{
    var horridFullscreenTimer:Timer;
    horridFullscreenTimer = new Timer(100,1);
    horridFullscreenTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,initializeViewForReal);
    horridFullscreenTimer.start();          
}

public function initializeViewForReal(event:TimerEvent=null):void
{
    stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
    stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
    stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
    stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, handleStageResize);
}
```

Solution was found in this thread: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/108170